# Overriding the Index view of class AdminSite for Django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I need to Override the `def index(self, request, extra_context=None):` view to perform some extra functionality but have no idea how/where do I make a class and inherit `class AdminSite` and override the view to just perform extra functionality. I dont need anything else to be changed but just want to override this view.

Thanks
Anks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893755/defining-a-custom-app-list-in-django-admin-index-page

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the need to overriding or extending the admin `index view` but i guess its fair to show something custom while showing the admin index page, If you want to add a couple of links of your own which looks neat and nice then [django-admin-tools](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [django-grappelli](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-grappelli/en/2.3.4/) will accomplish that. I've never tried it myself but there is a post i've seen few days back [on google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/c068abf238ea4597/3ce2d2f518fa671f?show_docid=3ce2d2f518fa671f) where a guy overrides/extends the admin index view with his own in `admin.py`.