# Defining a custom app_list in django admin index page

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to define a custom application list to use in django's admin index page because I want the apps displayed in a specific order, rather than the default alphabetical order. Trawling through various SO posts it would appear that it's not yet possible to declare the desired application order in any of the obvious places (e.g. admin.py, models.py).

Now, I can see that the django admin's index.html file contains the following statement:

```
{% for app in app_list %}
   # do stuff with the app object
```

So I'd like to change this to use a custom list object called, say, my_app_list. In python I'd do this along the following lines:

```
from django.db.models import get_app
my_app_list = [get_app('myapp1'), get_app('myapp2'), ..., get_app('django.contrib.auth')]
for app in my_app_list
   ...
```

My question then is, how do I code the equivalent of the first 2 lines above into my local copy of the index.html file?

Or, alternatively, what python source file should I insert those lines into such that the variable my_app_list is available within index.html.

Thanks in advance.

Phil

Comment: This worked fine for me => http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2613/

Comment: @Serafeim Thanks for this. I'll give it a go once I've resolved the various 32-bit vs 64-bit python/django problems that have cropped up as a result of our server being upgraded!

Answer (score 9):

Subclass `django.contrib.admin.site.AdminSite()`. Override the `.index()` method, and do something like this:

```
class MyAdminSite(django.contrib.admin.site.AdminSite):
    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if extra_context is None:
            extra_context = {}
        extra_context["app_list"] = get_app_list_in_custom_order()
        return super(MyAdminSite, self).index(request, extra_context)
```

Instantiate an instance of this subclass with `my_admin_site = MyAdminSite()`, attach your models to it (using the usual `my_admin_site.register()`), and attach it to the URLconf; that should do it.

(I haven't tried this, I'm basing this on my reading of the AdminSite source.)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - haven't had a chance to test it out yet. Will report back when I have. Looks like a viable option though.

Comment: the code fragment you've suggested makes sense, but it's not clear to me where it should reside. I started out placing it inside the admin.py module for one of my applications, but realised that doesn't make sense because it's a site-wide piece of code, and not specific to a particular application. Also, I wasn't sure how or why one would modify the URLconf to use this code since I haven't changed any urls.

Comment: Finally got round to trying this method. Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. Firstly, the get_app() function returns a module object, rather than the dict object expected by index.html (I should have read the source!). Secondly, by instantiating a subclass of AdminSite, and then registering your own apps against it, it seems you lose visibility of other apps (like Auth) which are registered against the default admin site object. Hence I couldn't find a way to configure things such that both default apps and your own apps appear together in the admin index view.

Comment: Continuing on from my previous comment ... it would seem therefore that the easiest way to control the order of apps in the admin index is not to bother trying to do something fancy with app_list, but simply to hard code the desired order in index.html. You'd then need to update that file every time you added a new app - not a big deal I guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind to use a subclass of `django.contrib.admin.site.AdminSite()`, as expected in cases when you need to [customize your admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite), I think it's a feasible idea rewriting "index" and "app_index" methods in the derived class. You can do custom ordering using two dictionaries that store the app declararion order in settings.py and the registration order of models.
Then rewrite the code of the original `AdminSite().index()` and `app_index()`, adding a custom order fields (`'order'`) in app_list and order by this field  despite `'name'`. This is the code, excluding `app_index()`, that is similar to `index()` function:

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):

    def __init__(self, name='admin', app_name='admin'):
        super(MyAdminSite, self).__init__(name, app_name)

        # Model's registration ordering. It's not necessary to
        # categorize by app.
        self._registry_ord = {}

        # App ordering determined by declaration
        self._app_ord = { 'auth' : 0 }
        app_position = 1
        for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
            self._app_ord[app] = app_position
            app_position += 1

    def register(self, model_or_iterable, admin_class=None, **options):
        super(MyAdminSite, self).register(model_or_iterable, admin_class, **options)

        if isinstance(model_or_iterable, ModelBase):
            model_or_iterable = [model_or_iterable]
        for model in model_or_iterable:
            if model in self._registry:
                if self._registry_ord:
                    self._registry_ord[model._meta.object_name] = max(self._registry_ord.values()) + 1 
                else:
                    self._registry_ord[model._meta.object_name] = 1

    @never_cache
    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        """
        Displays the main admin index page, which lists all of the installed
        apps that have been registered in this site.
        """
        app_dict = {}
        user = request.user
        for model, model_admin in self._registry.items():
            app_label = model._meta.app_label
            has_module_perms = user.has_module_perms(app_label)

            if has_module_perms:
                perms = model_admin.get_model_perms(request)

                # Check whether user has any perm for this module.
                # If so, add the module to the model_list.
                if True in perms.values():
                    info = (app_label, model._meta.module_name)
                    model_dict = {
                        'name': capfirst(model._meta.verbose_name_plural),
                        'perms': perms,
                        'order': self._registry_ord[model._meta.object_name]
                    }
                    if perms.get('change', False):
                        try:
                            model_dict['admin_url'] = reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist' % info, current_app=self.name)
                        except NoReverseMatch:
                            pass
                    if perms.get('add', False):
                        try:
                            model_dict['add_url'] = reverse('admin:%s_%s_add' % info, current_app=self.name)
                        except NoReverseMatch:
                            pass
                    if app_label in app_dict:
                        app_dict[app_label]['models'].append(model_dict)
                    else:
                        app_dict[app_label] = {
                            'name': app_label.title(),
                            'app_url': reverse('admin:app_list', kwargs={'app_label': app_label}, current_app=self.name),
                            'has_module_perms': has_module_perms,
                            'models': [model_dict],
                            'order': self._app_ord[app_label],
                        }

        # Sort the apps alphabetically.
        app_list = app_dict.values()
        app_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['order'])

        # Sort the models alphabetically within each app.
        for app in app_list:
            app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['order'])

        context = {
            'title': _('Site administration'),
            'app_list': app_list,
        }
        context.update(extra_context or {})
        return TemplateResponse(request, [
            self.index_template or 'admin/index.html',
        ], context, current_app=self.name)
```

If you use custom AdminSite and you want to include Auth models you probably need this, somewhere in your code (I made it in a specific app to [extend user information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from myproject import admin

admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Group)
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing what @AdminKG said copy the `index.html` file to the root of the `admin` directory that you need to create inside the `templates` directory you declared on you `setting.py`.

if you you have a clear sorting logic for `app_list` you can implement it in the `.index()` method of your `AdminSite`'s subclass. Otherwise you will need to hard code the app list on `index.html`.

To access something in your template just have it in your context, something like that:

```
def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
    context = {
        'app1':get_app('myappname'),
        'app2': get_app('mysecondappname'),
        # ...
    }
    context.update(extra_context or {})
    context_instance = template.RequestContext(request, current_app=self.name)
    return render_to_response(self.index_template or 'admin/terminal_index.html', context,
        context_instance=context_instance
    )
```

Now apps objects are available to use on your `index.htm`

Comment: "Otherwise you will need to hard code the app list on index.html." Indeed, that is the very nature of my question. How do I obtain, in my local index.html file, a handle to an app object given that I only know its name. I can use the get_app('myappname') function in python code. Is there an equivalent function in django's templating language? Maybe I'm barking up entirely the wrong tree!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are concerned about the order, you can find my solution helpful.
Basically, I created a filter, which moves desired elements of app_list to the beginning.

```
@register.filter
def put_it_first(value, arg):
    '''The filter shifts specified items in app_list to the top,
    the syntax is: LIST_TO_PROCESS|put_it_first:"1st_item[;2nd_item...]"
    '''
    def _cust_sort(x):
        try:
            return arg.index(x['name'].lower())
        except ValueError:
            return dist
    arg = arg.split(';')
    arg = map(unicode.lower, arg)
    dist = len(arg) + 1
    value.sort(key=_cust_sort)
    return value
```

However, if you need to remove some elements you can use:

```
@register.filter
def remove_some(value, arg):
    '''The filter removes specified items from app_list,
    the syntax is: LIST_TO_PROCESS|remove_some:"1st_item[;2nd_item...]"
    '''
    arg = arg.split(';')
    arg = map(unicode.lower, arg)
    return [v for v in value if v['name'].lower() not in arg]
```

Filters can be chained, so you can use both at the same time.
Filtering functions are not written the way which would make them speed demons, but this template is not being rendered too often by definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
app_list = admin.site.get_app_list(context['request'])
```

apply any sort on app_list