# Changing default admin url causing error in Django 1.4 site

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to change the default url for django admin from /admin to /djadmin so that I can use /admin for my own purposes.

So far all I have done is update the urls.py file, changing the admin url to

```
url(r'^djadmin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

and then adding my own

```
(r'^admin/', include('my_app.admin_urls')),
```

However when I now navigate to /admin I get the following error

```
Forbidden

You do not have staff privileges.
```

Which since I don't require this parameter I assume is coming from an internal django check.  If I change the user to have the `is_staff` flag checked then it works fine and redirects to my admin pages.

Is there something else I need to do to stop Django checking for the `is_staff` flag whenever I navigate to an admin url?

Answer (score 0):

The `is_staff` flag is wrapped in the code of Django admin site, because is intended to restrict the usage of this interface only to a subgroup of selected users (the ones that administrate the content of the website). The only way to remove it is to subclass the Django's admin site, so a your own custom site.

For admin site customization see [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite) or other answers like [the one I've posted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16811639/1838607). In the AdminSite subclass you have to override the `has_permission` method with:

```
def has_permission(self, request):
   return request.user.is_active
```

You also need to use a custom admin form (`AdminSite.login_form`) and modify the `base.html` template, removing references about `is_staff` in a pair of `if` statements.